# How do you create a toggle button?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a toggle button in html using css. I want it so that when you click on it  , it stays pushed in and than when you click it on it again it pops out.

If theres no way of doing it just using css. Is there a way to do it using jQuery?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The good semantic way would be to use a checkbox, and then style it in different ways if it is checked or not. But there are no good ways do to it. You have to add extra span, extra div, and, for a really nice look, add some javascript.

So the best solution is to use a small jQuery function and two background images for styling the two different statuses of the button. Example with an up/down effect given by borders:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a#button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: solid 2px #eaeaea;
  border-left: solid 2px #eaeaea;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #777;
  border-right: solid 2px #777;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

a.down {
  background: #bbb;
  border-top: solid 2px #777;
  border-left: solid 2px #777;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #eaeaea;
  border-right: solid 2px #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="button" title="button">Press Me</a>
```

Obviously, you can add background images that represent button up and button down, and make the background color transparent.

Comment: Here's a JS fiddle with this code so you can try it out live...

http://jsfiddle.net/LmULE/

Comment: FYI: I did the same thing as this post, only using Google Dart http://steelpinjata.com/2014/03/20/toggle-buttons-in-dart/. Note: works in Chromium, but can be compiled to JavaScript and will work in other modern browsers. IE does not count as a browser ;-)

Answer (score 51):

JQuery UI makes light work out of creating toggle buttons.  Just put this

```
<label for="myToggleButton">my toggle button caption</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myToggleButton" />
```

on your page and then in your body `onLoad` or your `$.ready()` (or some object literals `init()` function if your building an ajax site..) drop some JQuery like so:

```
$("#myToggleButton").button()
```

thats it. (don't forget the `< label for=...>` because JQueryUI uses that for the body of the toggle button..)

From there you just work with it like any other `input="checkbox`" because that is what the underlying control still is but JQuery UI just skins it to look like a pretty toggle button on screen.

Comment: Given that the OP added the jquery tag this is a great answer. Given jqueryUI could be used to provide congruent styling.

Answer (score 37):

here is an example using `pure css`:

```css
  .cmn-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -9999px;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .cmn-toggle + label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border-radius: 60px;
  }
  input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before,
  input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    bottom: 1px;
    content: "";
  }
  input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
    right: 1px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 60px;
    transition: background 0.4s;
  }
  input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
    width: 58px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: margin 0.4s;
  }
  input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
    background-color: #8ce196;
  }
  input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
    margin-left: 60px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20):

In combination with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309318/305189) answer, you can also use this kind of style that is like mobile settings toggler.

[image: togglers]

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="toggler">&nbsp;</a>
<a href="#" class="toggler off">&nbsp;</a>
<a href="#" class="toggler">&nbsp;</a>
```

**CSS**

```css
a.toggler {
    background: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-right-width: 15px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

a.toggler.off {
    background: red;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 15px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.toggler').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('off');
    });
});
```

Could be much prettier, but gives the idea.
One advantage is that it can be animated with CSS
[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/p44nr0rx/)

Answer (score 9):

If you want a proper button then you'll need some javascript. Something like this (needs some work on the styling but you get the gist). Wouldn't bother using jquery for something so trivial to be honest.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.on { 
border:1px outset;
color:#369;
background:#efefef; 
}

.off {
border:1px outset;
color:#369;
background:#f9d543; 
}
</style>

<script language="javascript">
function togglestyle(el){
    if(el.className == "on") {
        el.className="off";
    } else {
        el.className="on";
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="button" class="off" onclick="togglestyle(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

## Pure CSS with a minimalist approach

All you need is a checkbox with a background as the slider. The result is keyboard accessible.

```css
input {
  appearance: none;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle 12px, white 100%, transparent calc(100% + 1px)) #ccc -16px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

:checked {
  background-color: dodgerBlue;
  background-position: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Wonderful, so simple and elegant! No `label`, `div`, `span`, just an `input type="checkbox"`, perfect. Here is a [square-corner version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73053185) based on this one.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `toggleClass()` to track state. Then you check if button element has the class, like this:

```
$("button.toggler").click( function() {
    $me = $(this);
    $me.toggleClass('off');
    if($me.is(".off")){
        alert('hi');
    }else {
        alert('bye');
    }
});
```

And I use the `button` element for buttons for semantic reasons.

```
<button class="toggler">Toggle me</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an anchor element (`<a></a>`), and use a:active and a:link to change the background image to toggle on or off. Just a thought.

Edit: The above method doesn't work too well for toggle. But you don't need to use jquery. Write a simple onClick javascript function for the element, which changes the background image appropriately to make it look like the button is pressed, and set some flag. Then on next click, image and flag is is reverted. Like so

```
var flag = 0;
function toggle(){
if(flag==0){
    document.getElementById("toggleDiv").style.backgroundImage="path/to/img/img1.gif";
    flag=1;
}
else if(flag==1){
    document.getElementById("toggleDiv").style.backgroundImage="path/to/img/img2.gif";
    flag=0;
}
}
```

And the html like so
    `<div id="toggleDiv" onclick="toggle()">Some thing</div>`

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to use a class in your css that alters the border style or border width when the button is depressed, so it gives the appearance of a toggle button.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think using JS for creating a button is good practice. What if the user's browser deactivates JavaScript ?

Plus, you can just use a checkbox and a bit of CSS to do it.
And it easy to retrieve the state of your checkbox.

This is just one example, but you can style it how want.

http://jsfiddle.net/4gjZX/

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="toggle">
  <input id="data-policy" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <label for="data-policy">
  <div class="toggle-button">
    <div class="toggle-tab"></div>
  </div>
  Toggle
  </label>
</fieldset>​
```

**CSS**

```
.toggle label {
  color: #444;
  float: left;
  line-height: 26px;
}
.toggle .toggle-button {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eeeeee), to(#fafafa));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#eeeeee', EndColorStr='#fafafa');
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
}
.toggle .toggle-button .toggle-tab {
  width: 30px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fafafa), to(#eeeeee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #eeeeee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #eeeeee);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#fafafa', EndColorStr='#eeeeee');
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 4px -5px #000000, 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 4px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 4px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .toggle-button {
  background-color: #2d71c2;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2d71c2), to(#4ea1db));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2d71c2, #4ea1db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2d71c2, #4ea1db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2d71c2, #4ea1db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2d71c2, #4ea1db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #2d71c2, #4ea1db);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#2d71c2', EndColorStr='#4ea1db');
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .toggle-button .toggle-tab {
  margin-left: 39px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 4px -5px #000000, 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: -5px 0px 4px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 4px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}​
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There's a jquery plugin by [Swizec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520640/googles-imageless-buttons/566804#566804), which can do this among other things: https://github.com/Swizec/styled-button

(The old link was http://swizec.com/code/styledButton/, I didn't fully test the replacement, just found it w/Google.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this bit:

```
input type="button" 
                           data-bind="css:{on:toggleButton, off:toggleButton!=true},value:toggleButton,click: function() { $data.toggleButton(!($data.toggleButton()))}" />

in viewModel
self.toggleButton = ko.observable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach relies on html-css only, no js of any kind is needed.

**The css and the HTML snippet is as simple as this:**

```css
#mycbid
{
  display:none;
}

#mycbid:checked + #mylabelid
{
  background: grey;
  border: inset;
}

#mylabelid
{
  background: lightgray;
  border: outset;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mycbid">
  <label for="mycbid" id="mylabelid">Text of the label</label>
```

### Explication:

Under the hood the checkbox will not be displayed but still it can be set as checked or unchecked so it will be possible to use it more or less as usual.

When the checkbox is checked its status "triggers" the css rules under `#mycbid:checked + #mylabelid` and the label will be styled accordingly with it. This css selector is in fact the key of everything: in fact it selects the **sibling** of the checkbox (that is the label it self). The label redirects the click to the checkbox thanks to the **for** attribute, even if the checkbox is not shown.

When the checkbox is not checked its status "triggers" the css rules under `#mylabelid` and the label will be styled accordingly with it.

Of course it is possible to style the label in may different ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "active" pseudoclass (it won't work on IE6, though, for elements other than links)

```
a:active
{
    ...desired style here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was searching for answer too, and wanted to acomplish it with CSS. I found solution by CSS NINJA
It is a nice impelmentation of `<input type="checkbox">` and some css
[Live demo](http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/)!
Although it is not working in IE 8 you could implement [selectivizr](http://www.selectivizr.com)! and fix CSS where uses `opacity` to `filter` to make it work in IE.

EDIT 2014:

for new toggle buttons I do use solution found on [Lea Verou blog](http://lea.verou.me/2013/03/ios-6-switch-style-checkboxes-with-pure-css/) visually similar to iOS checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the example/variant (more detail described) of ToggleButton using jQuery with `<label for="input">` implementation.

1st we will create container for our ToggleButton using classic HTML `<input>` and `<label>`

```
<span>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="some_feature_to_select" id="feature_cb" style="display: none;"> <!-- We can hide checkbox bec. we want <label> to be a ToggleButton, so we don't need to show it. It is used as our value holder -->
  <label for="feature_cb" id="label_for_some_feature">
    <img alt="Stylish image" src="/images/icons/feature.png">
  </label>
</span>
```

Next we will define function for toggling our button. Our button actually is the usual `<label>` which we will be styling to represent value toggling.

```
function toggleButton(button) {

var _for = button.getAttribute('for'); // defining for which element this label is (suppose element is a checkbox (bec. we are making ToggleButton ;) )
var _toggleID = 'input#'+_for; // composing selector ID string to select our toggle element (checkbox)
var _toggle = $( _toggleID ); // selecting checkbox to work on
var isChecked = !_toggle.is(':checked'); // defining the state with negation bec. change value event will have place later, so we negating current state to retrieve inverse (next).

if (isChecked)
    $(button).addClass('SelectedButtonClass'); // if it is checked -> adding nice class to our button (<label> in our case) to show that value was toggled
else
    $(button).removeClass('SelectedButtonClass'); // if value (or feature) was unselected by clicking the button (<label>) -> removing .SelectedButtonClass (or simply removing all classes from element)
}
```

*Function is implemented in a reusable way. You can use it for more than one, two or even three ToggleButtons you've created.*

... and finally ... to make it work as expected, we should bind toggle function to an event ("change" event) of our improvised `<label>` button (it will be `click` event bec. we are not altering the `checkbox` directly, so no `change` event can be fired for `<label>`).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#some_feature_label").click(function () {
        toggleButton(this); // call function with transmitting instance of a clicked label and let the script decide what was toggled and what to do with it
    });

    $("#some_other_feature_label").click(function () {
        toggleButton(this); // doing the same for any other feature we want to represent in a way of ToggleButton
    });

});
```

With CSS we can define `backgorund-image` or some `border` to represent the change in value whilst `<label>` will do the job for us in altering the value of a checkbox ;).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: + this implementation seems to be working correctly on mobile devices as well, bec. CCS implementation proposed above by TDeBailleul was not working properly on Android (Android 2.3.5 default browser; Opera Mobile on the same system was Ok).

Comment: Also, instead of `.addClass()`/`.removeClass()` you can use `.toggleClass()`, but method described explicitly defines actions for `checked`/`unchecked` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
<li>Text To go with Toggle Button<span class = 'toggle'><input type = 'checkbox' class = 'toggle' name = 'somename' id = 'someid' /></span></li>
```

And make sure in the

```
<head><link rel = 'stylesheet' src = 'theme.css'> (from jqtouch - downloadable online)
      <link rel = 'text/javascript' src = 'jquery.js'> (also from jqtouch)
</head>
```

Remember when you are coding this, *only* `somename` and `someid` can change in the input tag, otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "square corners" version of @Mori's excellent [minimalist CSS-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70410909):

[image]

```css
.switch {
  appearance: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 52px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 22px, dodgerBlue 22px), 
                    linear-gradient(to right, white 0 22px, dodgerBlue 22px 60px);
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-position: 4px 4px;
}
.switch:checked {
  background-position: 26px 4px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="switch">
```

and a round one with two blue sides (no disabled gray side):

```css
.switch {
  appearance: none;
  padding: 16px 30px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle 12px, white 100%, transparent calc(100% + 1px)) dodgerBlue -14px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.switch:checked {
  background-position: 14px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="switch">
```