# In apache, if i go to https://example.com, all images/links are http://. Is there way to auto rewrite the html so it's all https://?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, zen-cart

I'm sure i've seen a feature in apache that can rewrite urls so you can point domain2.com at domain1.com and it rewrites everything domain1.com to domain2.com on the fly.

is there a similar thing for https?

In apache, if i go to https://example.com, the page itself is over https, but all images/links are http://. Is there way to auto rewrite the html so its all https://?

(it's running zen cart by the way)

Answer (score 4):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954327/hidden-features-of-html/960111#960111):

> Using a protocol-independent absolute
>   path:
>
> ```
> <img src="//domain.com/img/logo.png"/>
> ```
>
> If the browser is viewing an page in
>   SSL through HTTPS, then it'll request
>   that asset with the https protocol,
>   otherwise it'll request it with HTTP.
>
> This prevents that awful "This Page
>   Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure
>   Items" error message in IE, keeping
>   all your asset requests within the
>   same protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use absolute URLs everyhwere, this should work "automagically". So you only need to check two things:

- use relative URLs to point to resources on your own server and
- make sure you're not using `<base href="http://something">`

Answer (score 0):

You can just link to `/path/to/page.html` instead of `http://example.com/path/to/page.html`. That way, if it's HTTP it'll stay HTTP, and if it's HTTPS it'll stay HTTPS.

If Zen Cart is adding the domain to all links, though, you'll need to edit the software.

Answer (score 0):

The apache module you referenced is called mod_rewrite, and yes it can handle what you are asking for, although I agree with the above answers that using a protocol independent path is the best solution.