# How to get data from doPost method using JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, servlets

Since getJSON() method is used to get JSON data using an AJAX HTTP GET request.
Which method to use to get data from doPost method in servlet.
Say that I have used action to send the data to the servlet and want to get the response ..
Which JSON method to use..An example or a good tutorial would help

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're basically asking how to get JSON data by a POST request?

Instead of

```
$.getJSON('servleturl', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

use

```
$.post('servleturl', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

When you let the servlet do `response.setContentType("application/json")`, then the `data` is already in JSON format.

---

However, after reading your question and the comments once more, I think you're basically asking **how to submit a POST form using jQuery**. This has essentially nothing to do with JSON (although the servlet can return a JSON response if desired).

Assuming the following form

```
<form id="formid" action="servleturl" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

here's how you can "ajaxify" it (do it during document ready!)

```
$('#formid').submit(function() {
    $form = $(this);
    $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(data) {
        // Do something with response. Display message? Redirect to other page?
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

For another example also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114742/simple-calculator-in-jsp/4115298#4115298).

There exist plugins which do it more nicely, such as [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It's then as simple as

```
$('#formid').ajaxForm(function(data) {
    // Do something with response. Display message? Redirect to other page?
    alert(data);
});
```

and it also supports `<input type="file">` elements without much trouble.

Comment: @BalusC-Yes exactly...BalusC you seem to know lot about it..can u suggest me some good tutorials..little complex ones..Thanks:)

Comment: For JSP/Servlets, check the links at the bottom of our wiki pages: [JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [Servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). For jQuery, check the tutorials mentioned at [its homepage](http://jquery.com) (and I recommend the book "jQuery in Action"). For JSP/Servlet/jQuery combo, check those answers: [update current page with servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet) and [simple calculator in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114742/simple-calculator-in-jsp).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$.post(url, function(), return_type); //where return_type you replace with 'json'
```

So essentially `getJSON()` is just an alias for:

```
$.get(url, function(), 'json');
```

Here is a little plugin i made for `postJSON`:

```
(function($){
 $.postJSON = function(url, data, ret_fn) {
    return $.post(url, data, ret_fn, 'json');
 };
})(jQuery);
```

And here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/H8YeE/

Comment: @Neal- can you quote me an example...I am a begineer..It would be more clear..Also any good tutorials would help since the ones I saw were simple..Thanks:)

Comment: What do you mean, by `example`? i think i was pretty clear :-P

Comment: @Neal-Well $.post is sending the parameters to the servlet rite...What I meant was say I have sent the parameters through     <form id="LoginForm" method="post" action="Login">,then how do I retreive data from the server using JSON???why is'nt there a method like getJSON() for post??any particular reason??why not some thing like postJSON like getJSON()??

Comment: i just told u. do `$.post(url, function, 'json')`, that is `$.postJSON`, for some reason jQuery never made a `postJSON` method, but that is the same thing

Comment: @Neal...Made it neat and simple:)

Comment: @Neal-could understand it well..All doubts got cleared...tat s what I meant!!:)

Comment: ahhhh haaaa. but yet, you chose the more complicated answer :-p

Comment: I saw the answer before you editing...I have voted for yours:D I understood both answers..there should be an option to accept more than one answer...:P