# foward on button click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, redirect, forward

i want to foward or redirect a page after a $.ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').on('click', function(){

    var params = "";
    $('#tableResultat > tbody > tr').each(function(){
        $parent = $(this);
        params += $parent.find('td:eq(0)').attr('id') + ","  + $parent.find('td:eq(0)').text() + "," +  $parent.find('td:eq(1)').text() + ","  + $parent.find('td:eq(2)').text() +','+ $parent.find('td:eq(3)').text() +"|";
    });

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/resultat',
    data:{
            parametres : params
        }
}); 
});
});
```

and on my server side i have this :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException 
{
     String action = req.getServletPath();
     if(action.equals("/resultat"))
     {
         String params = req.getParameter("parametres");
        //save these value in DB 
         req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/vues/resultat.jsp").forward(req, resp);
         return;
     }   
}
```

I don't understand why when i click on my button it doesn't forward me to the resultat.jsp page ? what am i doing wrong ?

thanks for your awsers

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720961/jsp-requestdispatcher-forward-not-forwarding-when-servlet-called-via-ajax-pos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.ajax calls are supposed to receive the response and do something, by sending it a 'success' function.

So I think the best to do in your case is return the full URL (with http://) and do this on your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/resultat',
    data:{
            parametres : params,
            success : function(response){
                window.location.href = response;
        }
});
```

Comment: i did :  resp.getOutputStream().println("/resultat");

it works but i still don't know why the foward didn't work in the first place ! Thank you for your awnser i would've like to upvote it though i can't because I am new to stackOverflow.