# Jquery Ajax call to servlet

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make an Ajax call using JQuery to a servlet that returns a JSON object.
In the JSP page I have a form, at first I didn't know how the get the data from the form,
then I found .serialize.

I have the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function blabla() {
        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ArchiveSearch/Search",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
        });
    });
});
```

The information comes from the following form:

```
<form method= post">
            <div class="searchCiteria">
                <div id="searchValueBlock1">
                        <div><span class="label">Case ID:</span><input type="text" name="messagecaseid"  size="25"/></div>
                        <div><span class="label">Onderwerp:</span><input type="text" name="messagesubject" size="25" /></div>
                        <div><span class="label">Afzender:</span><input type="text" name="messagesender"  size="25"/></div>
                        <div><span class="label">Ontvanger:</span><input type="text" name="messagereceiver"  size="25"/></div>
                </div>

                <div id= "searchValueBlock2">
                    <div><span class="label">Datum:</span><input type="text" name="date1"  size="25"/></div>
                    <div><span class="label"></span><input type="text" name="date2"  size="25"/></div>

                    <div class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

When I use the action parameter in the form the servlet repondes like it should.
But I can't seem to get the Ajax call to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114742/simple-calculator-in-jsp The answer is basically a mini tutorial into using Ajax with JSP/Servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add the success param to ajax function
 
`$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ArchiveSearch/Search",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
 success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});`

Comment: It worked, the data var holds the response from the server right, im am asking because, when I do succes: function(data){alert(data)} I dont see any pop-up window

Comment: When I add an extra alert after the data function I do see both alerts

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the submit button is to `POST` the form, which will redirect the user to a URL of the `action` attribute ond the form. When you don't(which you should...) have an action attribute it will reload the page. To prevent the page from reloading you need to prevent the default behavior by returning `false` at the end of your `$("#submit").click` function.