# How to use ajax in jsp

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I wold like to know if its possible to insert ajax into jsp to prevent re-loading a page and if possible How?I have checked Stack overflow and discovered one for servlet, but not jsp.Thanks.

Comment: And what was the problem when reading the question?

Comment: Aren't Servlets quite different from jsp.I was thinking they are going to be implemented in different ways.Sorry am not quite good in use of jsp and Servlets, just learning.Thanks.

Comment: JSP is the view, Servlet is the controller. Note that in the question BalusC starts showing a JSP that will start the ajax request, and the Servlet is the controller that will handle the request and generate an appropiate response. Also, there's a [follow up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4114742/1065197).

Comment: Thanks.I will chck that out.