# getting the submit button value using jsp

Tags: html, jsp, submit

Dear All,
I have a form with multi submit buttons
like this

```
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" Action="SomePage.jsp">
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="submit" VALUE="Button 1">

        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="submit" VALUE="Button 2">

        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="submit" VALUE="Button 3">
    </FORM>
```

How can i get the submit value using JSP ?

Answer (score 12):

It's just by its name available as request parameter as well.

```
String submit = request.getParameter("submit");
```

#### See also:

- [Hidden features of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954327/hidden-features-of-html/1978039#1978039)

---

That said, a JSP is the [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) place to postprocess a form submit. Use a [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: result here will always be null

Comment: @mugumedavid: just ask a question if you want it solved.

Comment: @mugumedavid — It will not be `null`. A clicked submit button will with a name and value will be included in the form data just like any other successful form control.

Comment: @Quentin you are correct. This will work on servlets. Will upvote