# When you submit a form, does the button that was clicked get posted also?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When you submit a form, does the button that was clicked get posted also?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954327/hidden-features-of-html/1978039#1978039

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does. As long as you set both the `name` and `value`:

```
<INPUT name="submit" value="submit" type="submit"/>
```

In fact you can have multiple submit buttons on the same page and you can detect which one is clicked on by checking for this pair.

Comment: Using uppercase tags but xhtml-style tag closing = fail ;)

Comment: JS on MSIE has also some itchy issues when using `name="submit"` on a form element ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, submit buttons are submitted with their name/value.

But especially when doing i18n, it's recommended to rely only on the name, not the value though so you don't have to check for i18n'd values in your server-side code but just for the existence of certain POST arguments..

Answer (score 0):

If it is part of the submitted form, yes.
When a form is submitted, every one of it's "input" elements are posted; and if you submit a form by clicking it's submit button (which is another input) you'll definitely post it too.
If you don't want to do that, you can always submit you form via javascript : `form.submit();`.
You can add a button element to your form and attach a function that submits the form to it's click event.

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();">
    Submit the form!
</button>
```

That way you'll have a submit button inside your form that is not submitted:)