# What does Google Closure Library offer over jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-closure, google-closure-library

Considering

- business background
- community support
- available extensions
- default set of features
- simplicity of use
- and reliability

why do you prefer one over the another?

Comment: I think it will be hard to say why one is preferred over the other until people get to experiment with applications and see what the limits of closure is.

Comment: Some syntax comparisons here: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2010/06/google-closure-introduction.ashx

Comment: [This article](http://sayspy.blogspot.com/2010/10/lessons-learned-porting-from-jquery-to.html) may also help with the decision. Key lesson: **“Closure is an ecosystem. It is not like jQuery where you just use it here and there to make accessing or manipulating the DOM easier. If you want to truly use Closure, you have to make a commitment to truly use it.”**

Comment: **2019** What's google closure? :D

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I'll try to add my piece of information.

#### More than another JS lib

As I understand it, Google Closure is not only another JS library, but it is also a set of tools that will allow you to optimize your JS code. Working with jQuery gives you good tools and a lightweight library, but it does not minify your own code. The [Closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) will. The [closure inspector](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/inspector.html) may also be useful, as sometimes minified code has a different behavior than the original one, and is a pain to debug. It integrates with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and support unit tests, which are both developers' best friends nowadays.

#### Documentation

I guess that as any new library VS a well established one, it will lack the availability of tons of extensions and tutorial that jQuery has. However, being pushed by Google should ensure that support and reliability will be both pretty good. The current [documentation](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html) and [tutorial](http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/tutorial.html) both seem really good, too.

#### Features

The features of Closure look decent, though, and its modular architecture is promising, too. I guess Google has been using it internally for a long time, which means that you could expect all basic features (and more) to be implemented, and probably in a very optimized and scalable way. They are trying to present it as the STL of JavaScript, so they should have polished it.

After looking at the features more closely, it seems that this may be a step forward for web-applications development compared to existing libraries as jQuery. It guess it benefits internal developments at Google, but things like detecting the online state (see [goog.events.OnlineHandler](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_events_OnlineHandler.html)), easy integration of AJAX requests and JS actions in the browser history (see [goog.History](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_History.html)), or the legions of great widgets they provide (see [goog.ui package](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog_ui.html)) may help all of us building even more awesome webapps ;) !

It comes with [templates features](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/) that integrates with Java (who said [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) ?), so this may also be another plus for Closure.

#### Ease of use

Finally, it looks pretty simple to use. The syntax may be a bit more verbose than the short $ jQuery function, but with IDEs and auto-completion, it's not a real problem. Moreover, I'd say we can expect a good integration in IDEs like Eclipse, coming from Google.

EDIT: as requested, let me say a few words about the GWT reference. Google Web Toolkit is a Java library that allows to create AJAX-enabled web interfaces and that generates (and optimizes) the required JavaScript code. As Google Closure allows to create Templates that can be used both client- and server-side (using JavaScript and Java), my guess is that it will soon be possible to use them jointly (if it's not already the case).

Comment: Detailed and meaningful answer, thank you. Could you please explain what that reference to GWT means? I'm afraid I didn't get that.

Comment: I think you should also mention the template library (Soy) in your "More than" section. The same template file can be used in both server (Java) side and client side. Really nice implementation IMO. Means we can just send down JSON in AJAX queries rather than sending down HTML - saves bandwidth.

Comment: I just discovered a critique against Closure, but perhaps it's just FUD: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/11/12/google-closure-how-not-to-write-javascript/

Comment: The critique isn't FUD, and thanks for the link.  The critique is focused on how the javascript code isn't optimal everywhere.  This may be valid, but it misses the larger point.  As I understand it, Closure targets really complex JS applications (on the scale of GMail), and that has some consequences - such as not every line being optimal since everything isn't written by a single brilliant coder.  But conversely it might scale further as a software engineering framework.

Comment: @nalply that article does mention a whole number of pretty genuine performance issues with goog closure. I'm not a JS expert but I was actually thinking of using closure and that article convinced me not to.

Comment: @giddy: this article has been criticized quite a lot, and in my opinion you shouldn't worry about it too much: it's mostly just nit-picking on details that won't matter in most environments. No one cares about the "slow loop" if not iterating tightly on tens of thousands of elements, and the rant about arrays is completely ridiculous (feel free to do your own benchmarking on jsfiddle or jsperf). There are imperfections, but its maturity by **design** AND by **performance** is still - and again it is only my opinion - very suitable for enterprise development.

Comment: @giddy: Also, This critique is fairly old and there's been modifications to Closure since then. For a reference, Mike Bolin just released a book at O'Reilly, which I found a decent introduction (though sometimes obviously a bit-biased in favor of Closure, it also does pin-point some shortcomings). Your best bet to know if it's good is to try it out, and have a look at the code for yourself. You can always find stuff to nit-pick about in anyone's code, but to produce a *free* toolkit (library + compiler + templates + linter) with this degree of maturity is still an achievement.

Comment: a very good explanation indeed. I was just expecting this answer for my question that I asked just now.

Comment: @nalpy As suggested by the comments, this article didn;t mention that thelibrary gots a COMPILER (not a minifier) which might optimize these coding issues.

Answer (score 30):

In my brief look at the API I find the differences between jQuery and Closure to be striking.

jQuery is basically just a simplified way to do many frequent operations in a cross-browser way.

Closure is a framework that is very new, in that they provide a cross-browser way to use the `<canvas>` tag, for example, and they have added new events.

So, this is adding onto what we typically do with javascript, they are taking many operations that people want to do and putting them into the API.

For example, they have an event to tell if the online state has changed.  So you can tell if the system is online.

They have javascript functions that use tools such as Google Gears, which continues with the fact that they have extended what can be done with Javascript.

It will take me a couple of days to digest all the changes, but I can see that this could have a big impact on web applications that can be developed.

Answer (score 25):

The biggest advantage of Closure Library is that is is designed for Closure Compiler. This opens completely new possibilities for JavaScript development...

The compiler has several cool features:

- It compiles readable JavaScript into
  compressed machine-readable
  JavaScript - it has the **best compression ratio** in "ADVANCED" mode.
- Documentation of the code
  with JSDoc Tags is important: the
  compiler reads it and you get
  warnings during compilation for typos
  in documentation, wrong use of a
  @constructor, wrong **type of a
  variable**, misuse of a field annotated
  with @private and @protected, etc.
- If you write a reusable JavaScript
  library, such as OpenLayers or Google Maps, you
  formally export your public API - and
  the compiler optimizes your internal
  code.
- The end applications can be
  compiled together with the library -
  and then the unused parts of the
  library are removed from the produced
  code. Dependencies are solved
  automatically by the compiler.
- Compiler accepts constants to remove
  unwanted functionality - this allows
  compilation only for particular
  browser such as Mobile WebKit, for
  only one of Quirks mode or Strict
  mode, compilation without support of
  IE6, etc.
- Debugging with FireBug is
  possible even for the compiled
  version of the source code.
- Compiler supports generation of dynamically
  loadable modules, which can
  significantly speed up loading of the
  end application, because the code for
  advanced functionality can be loaded
  only when it is required.

For details have a look at:
http://blog.klokantech.com/2010/12/closure-compiler-for-openlayers-3x.html

Answer (score 20):

**Edit**: take a look at [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3uWx-fhjUc&feature=related) it may answer some questions about Google Closure better.

Probably the best sources of information on google closure are project [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss), wiki, doc pages, demos and a yet unfinished [book by Michael Bolin](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781449381882) that is now available from safari books site.

one thing I can tell right away - there is a steeper learning curve for `closure` vs `jQuery` but it may be well worth it due to the library's vastness, clear organization and the benefit of using it together with the compiler and the templating tool.

`closure` library in that respect is more like `dojo` than `jQuery`, and some concepts were borrowed from `dojo`, according to Michael Bolin.

google closure compiler uses `JSDoc` documentation system which simultaneously (if created by the programmer correctly) provides documentation and enables catching many errors at compile time.

while function names are more verbose than `jQuery`'s, the compiler shrinks the code (using various optimization tactics) and the type checking will save a considerable time debugging the code, so time typing in the longer names is probably not an issue. At the same time longer names add readability.

library supports browsers running in the quirks mode so that scripts could be embedded by other sites using "quirky" html

library works with (but does not depend upon) a javascript templating system called `soy` that simplifies filling documents with content.

like `jQuery` google `closure` allows traversing dom structure with the string-based queries using a dedicated component of the library.

`closure` library relies on dot-delimited namespaces more like `Java` - a very strong organizational feature.

using such namespaces will incur overhead in uncompiled code, but in the compiled code those things are replace with short variable names.

Comment: I was looking for something else and ended up here, but good to know `like jQuery google closure allows traversing dom structure with the string-based queries using a dedicated component of the library.` Can you please link me to some documentation related to it?

Comment: @iSid: I believe he talks about ``goog.dom.DomHelper``, but I personally don't see a query function equivalent to jQuery. @Evgeny: Can you give us more details?

Comment: @iSid: That functionality is provided by [goog.dom.query](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_third_party_closure_goog_dojo_dom_query.js.html), which is not documented as well as the rest of the goog.dom namespace.

Answer (score 8):

I just posted a pretty exhaustive article about Google Closure which answer this question on [insideRIA](http://www.developria.com/2009/11/google-closure-a-new-way-of-de.html).

...Closure rulez! ^_^

Comment: Nice to-the-point comparison to jQuery: "[...] jQuery work really well and make possible great things with no effort and fast, so the "promise" of Closure is not to offer better algorithms but rather a really better, *organized and maintainable way of deploying JavaScript applications* [...] Coding in Closure means thinking with object oriented principles in mind, create several js files, each representing a single class, organize the application architecture into packages and finally deploying it using the tools provided, obtaining a single, compressed, and safe JavaScript file [...]"

Answer (score 7):

Maybe I'm not getting jQuery, but I haven't seen a real UI widgets collection there (there are plugins, yes, but you never know how well-tested they are and often there is no clear winner and/or the plugin lacks documentation).

Closure has, among other things, [a widgets collection](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/docs/index.html) (see the demos tab), including, say, [imageless buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520640/googles-imageless-buttons) used in gmail.

More generally, it has more functionality implemented as part of the release. It may not be a big thing, but I get annoyed with the sea of jQuery plugins when I'm looking for something as simple as a ajax history module or autocomplete.

Overall it's a huge library + set of tools and I'll be getting acquainted with it just to know what's available.

Comment: jqueryui.com is the official ui widgets collection

Comment: yeah well, judging from the site it has 6 widgets:    Accordion
    Datepicker
    Dialog
    Progressbar
    Slider
    Tabs

Comment: I've used jQueryUI and I thought it was very weak. It hardly even seems to be in development. When was the last time a new widget was added. It may be the official widgets collection, but anyone looking for a widget to use with jQuery is better off just googling for third-party jQuery widgets.

Comment: jQueryUI isn't just a set of javascript widgets, it has a great css framework as well.   Its been a great tool for me in styling CRUD/admin pages.  Plus many of those Closure "Widgets" are 1-2 liners in jQuery, not even worth writing a plugin for.

Comment: The appeal of JQuery is not pre-made widgets. It's making your own custom widgets in record time. I rarely touch the plug-ins, including UI.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate most of Google's contributions to the open source community and I'm sure it's got some cool stuff but overall I find Closure bulky, overwrought, and inelegant. If you must turn everything into Java I suppose it's downright spiffy.

Edit:

Fair enough. I didn't really compare. Closure is like a giant warehouse with every possible tool you could possibly want located... somewhere. Sort of like .NET or a massive Java library. Once you find what you need, you can find highly specific stuff that does highly specific jobs. And then for production you can remove all the cruft.

JQuery on the other hand, is more of an easily modified sonic screwdriver.

Comment: I'd like to learn more about the Java version of Closure. Do you have a link for this. Thanks

Comment: Look up 'irony tags.' You'll find the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Closure Library allows you to compile and optimize your JavaScript. It's not a library like jQuery is. jQuery is something that provides you with functions that allow you to write your own javascript faster.

Google Closure would help you make your own javascript code minimized to allow for a speedier delivery over the Internet.

Long story short, Google Closure is a tool while jQuery is a library similar to Prototype.

Comment: That is not exactly true. Google Closures also comes with its own library that is similar to jQuery and that provides functions and utilities to write your own code : http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: +1 For trying to be helpful :)