# What documentation generator does Google use?

Tags: documentation-generation

Google has a uniform documentation of all its apis. I wonder what documentation generator does it use and is it available for public use. It has good TOC and other features. Also the code appears neat.

Can anyone shed more light on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to generate Javascript API documentation like the Google Closure Library API Documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818875/is-there-a-way-to-generate-javascript-api-documentation-like-the-google-closure)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but i think they are using Doxygen.Doxygen is a documentation system for C++, C,Java, Objective-C, Python, IDL (Corba and Microsoft flavors) and to
some extent PHP, C#, and D.If you are working on Linux/Unix then you also generate pdf files as well.Many companies are using this. To know more [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl)

Comment: What makes you think they're using Doxygen?  I know Doxygen's output is somewhat flexible (and you can add new formats), but I've never seen it generate documentation even vaguely like Google's.