# CSS: change buttons layout

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

What's the easiest solution to customize default buttons in the web pages ?

I need to change the button shape, from this:

> [Default Mac-like button  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/button1.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/button1.png)

to this:

> [Gmail like button http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/button2.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/button2.png)

I prefer to not use javascript, and I only need cross-browser solutions (IE included).

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google's Imageless Buttons...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520640/googles-imageless-buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is CSS.

Look at this [examples](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/top-10-css-buttons-tutorial-list).

Answer (score 1):

Well, use CSS :

```
input[type=submit] {
  border:#efefef;
  padding:2px 5px;
  background:url('your/gradiented/background') repeat-y;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Something like that. Customize according to your tastes.