# Make a 3D button with rounded edge

Tags: html, css, button, 3d

I am developing a website in which i want to implement 3D buttons with rounded edges.So for that i need to create a CSS file.I search alot about 3D button but nothing has worked for me as yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://css3button.net/

Comment: That site and the generated buttons don't work correctly in Opera. However, if you run the generated CSS through http://prefixr.com/ it should work.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use a combination of the following css styles: `border`, `border-radius`, `background`, `text-shadow` and finally `box-shadow`.

To achieve the 3D effect with these you need to use the [**gradient**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient) value on the `background` style.

There is a useful tool for making cross browser gradient css here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

And here is some example `CSS` that can style an `a` tag:

```
.button {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px;

    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid #427AA8 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;

    /* Gradient */
    background: #427AA8;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #59A3E0 1%, #427AA8 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#59A3E0), color-stop(100%,#427AA8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #59A3E0 1%,#427AA8 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #59A3E0 1%,#427AA8 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #59A3E0 1%,#427AA8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #59A3E0 1%,#427AA8 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#59A3E0', endColorstr='#427AA8',GradientType=0 );

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
}

.button:hover {
    background: #59A3E0;
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: none;
}​

<a href="#" class="button">Example Button</a>
```

And example of what you can make: **[jsfiddle.net/UPTyw](http://jsfiddle.net/UPTyw/)**

This works well with all modern browsers and ok with IE8-6 (which don't support `border-radius`). This method also uses no images.

Also checkout this question, [Google's Imageless Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520640/googles-imageless-buttons), which explains how Google have created their range of `CSS` buttons.

### IE9 Bug

IE9 has a bug with rendering `border-radius` if `filter` is set. The fix is to add the following IE9 only `CSS` to any elements using css gradients.

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/

When you finished styling your button, click on it and the corresponding CSS will appear in the box at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
button {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>

<button>Test</button>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/wPcn3/