# How to use Font Awesome with a button?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use a toggle button and found a [perfect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309318/903011). I [adapted the code](http://jsfiddle.net/fc6bf8Le/1/) to use a [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon:

```
<a id="button1" title="button1"><i class="fa fa-bluetooth fa-5x"></i></a>
<a id="button2" title="button2"><span id="mytext">large text</span></a>
```

The result is that neither the icon nor plain text expand the button:

[image]

**What is the way to automatically the size of a button to the size of the underlying text?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a display property to the anchor.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a#button1').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: solid 2px #eaeaea;
  border-left: solid 2px #eaeaea;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #777;
  border-right: solid 2px #777;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  display: inline-block; /* add display property */
}
a.down {
  background: #bbb;
  border-top: solid 2px #777;
  border-left: solid 2px #777;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #eaeaea;
  border-right: solid 2px #eaeaea;
}
#mytext {
  font-size: 3em; /* better you use em's rather than pt's */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="button1" title="button1"><i class="fa fa-bluetooth fa-5x"></i></a>
<a id="button2" title="button2"><span id="mytext">large text</span></a>
```